# Uncover a dialogue of a movie script to count the words spoken by characters

Tags: python, text, nltk, movie

I'm working on a project about the meaning of women in movies.
Therefore I'm analyzing movie scripts to get a ratio of spoken words by main male character/main female character.

I'm having a problem to filter the spoken words from the NAMES and the 
directing instruction.

I thought about regex, but I'm not into it.

For example:

```
Mia works, photos of Hollywood icons on the wall behind her, as --

                        CUSTOMER #1
           This doesn't taste like almond milk.

                        MIA
           Don't worry, it is. I know sometimes it --

                        CUSTOMER #1
           Can I see the carton?

 Mia hands it over. The Customer looks.

                        CUSTOMER #1 (CONT'D)
           I'll have a black coffee.
```

I've no idea what to do with the blank new line after the spoken text.
Any ideas how to reduce the complete movie script to an only dialogue script, where I can count the words and work with the data?

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

f = open("/...//La_la_land_script.txt", "r")
script = f.read()
```

I'm loading the movie script into python

```
def deletebraces (str):
    klammerauf = str.find('(')
    klammerzu = str.find(')')

    while (klammerauf != -1 and klammerzu != -1):

            if (klammerauf<klammerzu):
                str = str[:klammerauf] + str[klammerzu+1:]

            klammerauf = str.find('(')
            klammerzu = str.find(')')
    return str
```

This function deletes all brackets

```
def removing(list):
    for i in list:
        if i == '?':
            list.remove('?')
        if i == '!':
            list.remove('!')
        if i == '.':
            list.remove('.')
        if i == ',':
            list.remove(',')
        if i == '...':
            list.remove('...')
    return list
```

This function deletes all the other symbols

```
def countingwords(list):
    woerter = 0
    for i in list:
        woerter = woerter + 1
    return woerter;
```

this function counts the words

```
script = deletebraces(script)

def wordsspoken(script, name):

    a = 0
    e = 0
    all = -len(name)-1

    if script.find(name)==-1:
        print("This character does not speak")
```

Checks whether there is the character with the name

```
    else:
        while(a != -1 and e != -1):

            a = script.find(name+'\n            ') + len(name)
            print(a)
            temp = script[a:]
            t = temp.split("\n")

            text = t[1]

            print(text)
            textlist = word_tokenize(text)

            removing(textlist)                

            more = countingwords(textlist)

            all = all + more

            script = script[a+e:]
            a = script.find(name +'\n           ')
            temp = script[a:]
            e = temp.find(' \n')
```

Here I try to uncover, but it doesnt work at all

```
    print(name + " sagt " + str(all) + " Wörter.")

f.close()


name = input("Enter name:")
wordsspoken(script, name)
name1 = input("Enter another name:")
wordsspoken(script, name1)
```

Comment: you want to remove the speaker identifiers and achieve a text file that only contains the spoken lines?

Comment: Can you please share your code with us? What did you try so far, what is the exact problem you are facing? Since you are new here, can you please read how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? Also taking a tour would be nice, to get some clue on what this site is about (hint: we will not write your code for you, this is also not a discussion forum, this is Q&A site)

Comment: @rsm Ye for sure, I will have a look! Code added

Comment: great :) now, can you please improve your question a bit further, and format your code to be more readable (ie by deleting unnecessary blank lines and making sure indentation is ok? `script = deletebraces(script)` looks out of place to begin with).

Comment: also - can you please provide description to your code? what does it do, why? there are functions to remove some character, to count words etc - how does it relates with your problem of reading spoken text? and again - what is exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @duhaime Yes exactly, and w/o the director instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AdrianMcCarthy noted, the whitespace in your file has all the information you need to parse out the spoken lines. Here's one way to approach the task in Python:

```
import codecs

# script.txt contains the sample text you posted
with codecs.open('script.txt', 'r', 'utf8') as f:

  # read the file content
  f = f.read()

  # store all the clean text that's accumulated
  spoken_text = ''

  # split the file into a list of strings, with each line a member in the list
  for line in f.split('\n'):

    # split the line into a list of words in the line
    words = line.split()

    # if there are no words, do nothing
    if not words:
      continue

    # if this line is a person identifier, do nothing
    if len(words[0]) > 1 and all([i.isupper() for i in words[0]]):
      continue

    # if there's a good amount of whitespace to the left, this is a spoken line
    if len(line) - len(line.lstrip()) > 4:
      spoken_text += line.strip() + ' '

print(spoken_text)
```

Comment: That helped me a lot! Now I'm looking for a way to get the text spoken by MIA for example. Where do I ask for that?

Comment: @tgtrmr I'd ask a new question for that task. If you do so, feel free to ping me in a comment and I'll send a reply!

Comment: How do I ping you in another question? same way like @duhaime?

Comment: @tgtrmr exactly! You may need to do so in a comment. I'm not sure if references with the @username syntax in the body of a question will ping `username`...

Answer (score 3):

In script format, the indentation carries most of the information.  Tokenizing probably reduces the white space, causing a loss of the information you need.

I would use the indentation to separate stage directions from dialogue *before* tokenization.  If the line starts at the first column, it's a stage direction.  If it starts near the middle of a line and it's in all caps, it's the name of a character about to speak.  The lines after the character name that are indented (but not as much as the character name) are the dialogue.

Dialogue sometimes has some minor stage directions embedded, (e.g., to indicate if the character is whispering or yelling).  These are usually indented deeper than the dialogue itself and surrounded by parentheses.

Post-production scripts (e.g., those for the editor, sound editor, publication, etc.) are usually very rigorous about these rules, so the indentation will be very reliable.  Early drafts and spec scripts often have errors, too, but Hollywood is pretty standardized on one software package for scripts, so I'd expect anything modern to still be highly reliable.  Be aware that half-hour sitcom scripts are typically double-spaced but otherwise follow the same formatting rules as television dramas and motion pictures.